# Using mod_rewrite or htaccess to apply 301's to entire site structure, with URL's built using query strings

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am taking over an old website, and need to change the domain name.

The current domain is http://www.example.com/folder/ and the new domain is http://example.school.nz

An example of an existing and desired URL is:
Before: http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?page=sport
Desired: http://example.school.nz/about-us/sport

The site is built using CMSMS (http://www.cmsmadesimple.org), so pages and URL's are generated through the CMS, although it's easy enough to export a list of URL's.

Ideally I could set up 301 redirects for the entire site so the user doesn't get 404'd. Any clues to the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: +1 for clarity in problem statement, sample input and output.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how general you want things to be, but this set of rules will do what you asked in your question:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=sport
RewriteRule ^folder/index.php http://example.school.nz/about-us/sport? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So do you need to do this for every URL? And where do you place this, in an htaccess file which sits in the site root?

Comment: Well it depends whether there is a pattern or not. You typically want to avoid a large number of rewrite rules though, so you want to cram as much as you can into as few rules as possible. Yes you place this in the .htaccess file in the document root.

Comment: By pattern, I mean if for example you want to redirect `index.php?page=whateverishere` to `about-us/whateverishere` then that could be a single rule. It's even OK if you have a general rule and then some exceptions - that could work as well. You just take care of the exceptions first, then apply the general rule.

Comment: In that case, you might consider using a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) and make life simpler for yourself. You would make a plain text file with two columns - old page and new page, and then have a single rewrite rule that looks up how to rewrite from the map file.